# Importing fields into A&M Forms plugin

Tags: craft2, import, plugin-amforms

I'm currently using the A&M Forms plugin and was wondering if I can import fields from the native Craft 2 fields?  I have already created 20 or so fields that I will use in both the native sections and the A&M Forms sections.

Answer (score 1):

I believe A&M Forms stores its fields separately, it does not use the Craft fields that you would use elsewhere. You'll probably need to re-create those fields *through A&M Forms* to be able to access them in your forms.

To be honest, you should probably stop using A&M Forms if you are not in too deep. It was never ported to Craft 3 (and never will be), so your site will be stuck on Craft 2 unless you put in significant effort later to switch form plugins.

Comment: Thanks!  What would your recommendation be, as far as plugin and templating, in re-creating the functionality of a legacy form (originally in Classic ASP) which will do things like make the form visible within a certain date range, put data from form fields into the subject line of the email that gets to recipient(s) (which may also be from form data)?  Thanks!

Comment: Your options mostly boil down to [Contact Form](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/tree/v1) (free), [Sprout Forms](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms) (paid), or [Freeform](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform) (paid). Since your needs seem to be somewhat complex, I'd recommend either Sprout Forms or Freeform.